# evenly spreading data in to multiple columns

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport

I need to create a jasper report that contains two columns of data of equal length.  For example, I have a collection of 50 columns.  I want precisely two columns of 25 entries each.  How can I do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

## Using iReport

1. Start iReport.
2. Click **File » New**.
3. Click **Open this template**.
4. Click **Next**.
5. Click **Finish**.
6. Click **report1** in the **Report Inspector**.
7. Scroll down in the **Properties** panel until you see **Columns**.
8. Change **Columns** from `1` to `2`.
9. Scroll down until you see **Print order**.
10. Change the value to `Horizontal`.

The page content should divide in half. Place the objects in the left-hand side of the page.

## Using Jaspersoft Studio

1. Open JasperSoft Studio 5.6.
2. Open Report
3. Click report name in the Outline view
4. In Report Properties, click Report
5. Scroll down to "Edit Page Format"
6. Change the columns

By printing the object values across the page, rather than down each column, the results will split evenly between the two columns. (A horizontal print order will prevent a lopsided split.)