# repeat all columns multiple times in jasper report

Tags: java, jasper-reports, report

I have a requirement like the following but can't solve it and that's why I am here. I hope someone can help.

I need a report which contains 3 columns in jasper report. The column values are so small that all these 3 columns occupy just the one third of the page width. So, I want to make a report which is like as follows:

```
Col1   Col2   Col3  | Col1   Col2   Col3  | Col1   Col2   Col3
------------------    ------------------    ------------------
val1   val1   val1  | val3   val3   val3  | val5   val5   val5
val2   val2   val2  | val4   val4   val4  | val6   val6   val6
```

That means, `Col1 Col2 Col3` will be repeated.

Can you give me any suggestion regarding these issues in jasper report?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4294779/evenly-spreading-data-in-to-multiple-columns) solves my problem :)

This is really a nice post. Exact problem as of mine.

Comment: You can probably accept your answer here now, I think.